# UIActivityViewController In iOS 7 Missing Options

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I was using the following code with iOS 6 SDK to implement UIActivityViewController:

```
-(IBAction)Share:(id)sender
{    
    NSArray *activityItems = @[self.title, urlString];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

      [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];


    [activityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed)
     {
         NSLog(@"Activity = %@",activityType);
         NSLog(@"Completed Status = %d",completed);

         if (completed)
         {
             UIAlertView *objalert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Successfully Shared" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [objalert show];
             objalert = nil;
         } else
         {
             UIAlertView *objalert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Unable To Share" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [objalert show];
             objalert = nil;
         }
     }];
}
```

The above code in iOS 7 is giving me the following output:

[image: ios share facebook twitter uoactivityviewcontroller]

Earlier there wasn't Facebook and Twitter in the share sheet but i signed into both both these apps in the Settings and Facebook and Twitter started appearing.

**PROBLEM:** Belo the line, there is only COPY and other like BOOKMARK, ADD TO READING LIST, ADD TO HOMESCREEN, PRINT and AirDrop buttons are not showing up. What can i do to bring these? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I have added the print button by using one answer below, how can i add the rest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bookmark, Add To Reading List, and Add To Homescreen are only available in safari, unless you define them yourself. To add those buttons, you need to create an `applicationActivities` `NSArray`, populated with [`UIActivity`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActivity) objects for various services. You can pass this array into the `initWithActivityItems:applicationActivities:` `UIActivityViewController` method (you were passing nil for this parameter).

Comment: Can you update your answer with the code for adding all these? I have added the print button by taking help from another answer to this question. Thanks!

Comment: @AJ112 Add to reading list is added automatically when you follow @ArkadiuszHolko 's answer. This may also add "Add To Homescreen", but I am not sure. These sharing options may only be available in safari. You should just be able to populate `activityItems` with `NSURL`, `NSString`, or many other data types (like images), and then other choices will appear in the menu.

Comment: ok i have used that answer and "Add To Reading List" has appeared. Print is also there with the other answer on this question. Only Bookmark and Add To Home Screen are left. How can i bring those? Thanks!

Comment: @AJ112 I don't think those are possible in apps other than safari

Comment: Yes my fault. Print and Add To Reading List are enough. I am already offering an app and it doesn't make any sense to Add it on the homescreen because the app is already there. Thanks!

Comment: @SantaClaus  can't get you..i have same problem  BOOKMARK, ADD TO READING LIST, ADD TO HOMESCREEN, PRINT this option is not there..please give clear solution

Answer (score 3):

You should use UISimpleTextPrintFormatter to show PRINT:

```
UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *printData = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc]
                                             initWithText:self.title];
NSArray *activityItems = @[self.title, printData];
```

Follow @Arkadiusz Holko and @Santa Claus answers to add another functionality.

Comment: ok i added the print button with the code you provided. How can i add the rest? can you update your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Add UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList to the array

Answer (score 1):

You should use `NSURL` object instead of `NSString` when you want an element to be treated as a URL. Replace:

```
NSArray *activityItems = @[self.title, urlString];
```

with

```
NSArray *activityItems = @[self.title, [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

Then follow @Santa Claus's advice if you want elements other than `Add to Reading List` to be visible.